# Verify whole json response in jmeter by value or sort Json

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm not using JMeter too often, and I've run into very specific issue.

My REST response is always "the same", but nodes are not in the same order due to various reasons. As well, I can't put here whole response due to sensitive data, but let's use these dummy one:

First time response might be:

```
{
  "properties":{
  "prop1":false,
  "prop2":false,
  "prop3":165,
  "prop4":"Audi",
  "prop5":true,
  "prop6":true,
  "prop7":false,
  "prop8":"1",
  "prop9":"2.0",
  "prop10":0

  }
}
```

Then other time it might be like this:

```
{
  "properties":{
  "prop2":false,
  "prop1":false,
  "prop10":0,
  "prop3":165,
  "prop7":false,
  "prop5":true,
  "prop6":true,
  "prop8":"1",
  "prop9":"2.0",
  "prop4":"Audi"

  }
}
```

As you can see, the content it self is the same, but order of nodes it's not. I have 160+ nodes and thousand of possible response orders.

Is there an easy way to compare two JSON responses comparing matching key - values, or at least to sort the response, and then compare it with sorted one in assertion patterns?

I'm not using any plugins, just basic Apache JMeter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably have to do this with a JSR223 Assertion and Groovy.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion
- http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

Note that if you know Python, you might look at using Jython + JSR223.

Comment: Hi, I've been looking into JSR223 and Groovy, but I still don't see how to sort / use single assertion. I could go with multiple assertions, but that's tedious and too expensive, since I have 160+ properties in my JSON response. I've managed to to it quickly and easily in Python, but can't find similar thing for jMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked using Jython, you need to download the [Jython Library](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and save to your jmeter lib directory.

I've checked 2 JSONs with Sampler1 and Sampler2, on Sampler1 I've add a BeanShell PostProcessor with this code:

```
vars.put("jsonSampler1",prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

On Sampler2 I've add a BSF Assertion, specifying jython as the language and with the following code:

```
import json

jsonSampler1 = vars.get("jsonSampler1")
jsonSampler2 = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

objectSampler1 = json.loads(jsonSampler1)
objectSampler2 = json.loads(jsonSampler2)

if ( objectSampler1 != objectSampler2 ):
    AssertionResult.setFailure(True)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("JSON data didn't match")
```

Yoy can find the whole jmx in [this GistHub](https://gist.github.com/alphamikevictor/bd20c329e25d0e8494fb)

Answer (score 0):

I would just set up 10 jp@gc - JSON Path Assertions. Documentation for figuring out JSON Path format is [here](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) and you can test how it would work [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$.store.book[*].author).

For your example you would the assertion (Add > Assertion > jp@gc - JSON Path Assertions), then to test the prop 1 put:

```
$.properties.prop1
```

in the JSON Path field, click the Validate Against Expected Value checkbox, and put

```
false
```

in the expected value field. Repeat those steps for the other 9 changing the last part of the path to each key and the value you expected back in the expected value field.

This extractor is jmeter add on found [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/).

Comment: After reading reading your comment on previous answer, I now realize this may be a bit too tedious for 160+ nodes, let me know if you find anything more efficient in Jmeter. Hopefully this answer will be helpful for people with simpler problems.